# System.Collections.Immutable types: why no .Equals

Tags: c#, .net, immutability

```
var a = ImmutableList<int>.Empty.Add(1).Add(2).Add(3);
var b = ImmutableList<int>.Empty.Add(1).Add(2).Add(3);

Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); // False
```

In the code above the `a.Equals(b)` calls `Object.Equals`, because `ImmutableList<T>` doens't override `Equals(object)`, and as `ImmutableList<T>` is a reference type `Object.Equals` does (the useless) reference comparison.

**Question: Why doesn't `ImmutableList<T>` override `.Equals`? It would be straightforward and expected to have it compare each contained object with `.Equals` and return the result based on those comparisons. It would even be consistent to test rest of the framework (see `class String` )**

note: the above code is tested with `System.Collections.Immutable.1.1.38-beta-23516`

Comment: Most reference types in the .NET framework does not override `Equals`. Why do you expect that this type should do that?

Comment: I find it kinda sad that there is no standard/canonical/expected way of logical equality checking across the framework. For string, we can use ==, for collections it is sequenceequal, for some random type, well, who knows, because there is no standard

Comment: Perhaps there is no "standard" but you can certainly make assumptions that are true for most general purpose types: Reference types do not override `Equals` and are only equal if the references are equal. Value types override `Equals` and will implement `==` etc. `String` is special. It is a reference type but behaves a lot like a value type so it overrides `Equals` and implement `==` so different instance of the same string are equal.

Comment: @MartinLiversage - it's pretty standard for immutable types to implement value-based equality checking by default. See, for example, the `List` type in Microsoft F#. This is a pretty dumb oversight in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You want to do is test the *contents* of the collections for equality. No .NET collections override `Equals` to do this. Instead, use `SequenceEqual`:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.SequenceEqual(b));
```

As to *why* -- that's a matter of opinion, I suppose. Most reference oriented platforms do their best to not confuse reference equality with content equality.

`String` is actually very special case and though it does implement `IEnumerable`, isn't typically treated as a proper container in the sense that `List`/etc. are.

Answer (score 2):

You 'could' create a wrapper class and override the Equality and HashCode methods...  This could be helpful for c# records so that you don't have to keep overriding the auto generated methods.

```
    public sealed class ImmutableListSequence<T>
    {
        public ImmutableListSequence(ImmutableList<T> items)
        {
            Items = items;
        }

        public ImmutableList<T> Items { get; }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return Items.Aggregate(0, (agg, curr) => (agg * 397) ^ (curr != null ? curr.GetHashCode() : 0));
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            if (obj is ImmutableListSequence<T> second)
            {
                return Items.SequenceEqual(second.Items);
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the collections do.  They all inherit `Object.Equals(Object)` and don't override it.  Use [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx) method to compare elements of two collections.

Comment: This is a big problem for records

Comment: @ChristianFindlay How is it a problem?

Comment: It means that you need to override the default Equals method on records with collection properties because they won't be equal by default. That's despite the fact that they may contain exactly the same thing.

Comment: Or just use Enumerable.SequenceEqual.

Comment: As I said above, in the case of records, you need to override the default Equals method on records with collection properties. That would mean including a call to SequenceEqual()

Comment: I agree with @ChristianFindlay - this means that ImmutableCollections don't "just work" for record comparisons (in the same way that primitive properties, strings, and nested records do).